# Django - Error while trying to iterate a model class (db table) in views.py (need to compare dates)?

Tags: python, django, model

The idea is to compare a checking date & a checkout date stored , with checking & checkout dates obtained from a html file (hotel booking, with this I'm trying to see if there are habitaciones [rooms] available)

****Code in views.py *****

def reservas(request):

```
pickerR = request.POST.get('pickerR', None)

pickerR_checkout = datetime.datetime.strptime(pickerR, '%d/%m/%Y') #convierto la fecha de tipo string a datetime

pickerL = request.POST.get('pickerL', None)

pickerL_checking = datetime.datetime.strptime(pickerL, '%d/%m/%Y')  #convierto la fecha de tipo string a datetime

habitaciones = Habitacion.objects.all()

for hd in habitaciones:
    if Habitacion[hd].fecha_checkout >= pickerL_checking and  pickerR_checkout <= Habitacion[hd].fecha_checking:
        cantHabitaciones = `enter code here`int(request.POST.get('cant_habitaciones'))
        cantH = (request.POST.get('cant_huespedes'))
        tipo_habitaciones = models.tipoHabitacion.objects.all()
```

#code In models.py

class Habitacion(models.Model):

```
precio = models.IntegerField()    
numero = models.IntegerField()
disponible = models.BooleanField()
tipo = models.ForeignKey(tipoHabitacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
fecha_checking = models.DateField('%d/%m/%Y')
fecha_checkout = models.DateField('%d/%m/%Y')
```

error message:

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/reservas.html/
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: TypeError

Exception Value:'ModelBase' object is not subscriptable

Exception Location: /home/yamil/adaw2/hotel-Django/hotel/hotel/hotelApp1/views.py, line 94, in reservas
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.5

94. if Habitacion[h].fecha_checkout <= pickerL_checking and pickerR_checkout <= Habitacion[h].fecha_checking:

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You should add your code and error as text in the body of your post - not as pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be in the way you iterate over `habitaciones`.

You query:

> habitaciones = Habitacion.objects.all()

But then, when you iterate over that list, you put object in the object itself (Habitacion is not a list, it is a model):

> if Habitacion[h].fecha_checkout >= pickerL_checking...

Try replacing  it likes this:

> if h.fecha_checkout >= pickerL_checking and pickerR_checkout <= h.fecha_checking:

Let me know if that helps.